# Position sub menus under relative parent menus

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, navigation

I have a menu in a horizontal list and vertical submenus below. I have a simple JQuery script that shows the child `<ul>` when a parent is hovered over:

```
$('#menulist li').hover(
function() {
  $(this).children('ul').stop().fadeIn(200);
},
function () {
    $(this).children('ul').stop().fadeOut(200);
  }
);
```

My issue is that the child ul do not position themselves under their respective parent list items.

Short of hard coding a margin-left for each child UL, does anyone know a way to get around this?

Recreation of issue here: http://jsfiddle.net/MeltingDog/S8smw/5/

CSS:

```css
#menulist ul li {
  display: inline;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-right: 10px; 
}

#menulist ul li ul{
    display:none;
    background-color:#FFF;
    padding: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

Comment: give the `li` position relative.

Comment: @Musa sorry: that makes no difference

Comment: Are you sure http://jsfiddle.net/mowglisanu/S8smw/8/

Comment: Ah cool! Sorry I must have done something wrong when I tried

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `position:relative` to the parent `li`, as follows, also give some offset to the child `ul`:

```css
#menulist ul li {position:relative;}
#menulist ul li ul{top:30px;left:0;}
```